# ExtJs the same id and itemId

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've got old project written in ExtJs 4.2 and I'm trying to make it more component oriented.

For example I've got the following existing code:

```
Ext.define("CCH3.view.motivationschema.DealersTab", {
    extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
    xtype: "dealerstab",
    title: "Dealers",
    store: "admin.Users",

    layout: {
        type: "border"
    },

    region: "center",
    xtype: "tabpanel",
    layout: { type: "vbox", align: "stretch" },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: "panel",
            layout: { type: "vbox", align: "stretch" },
            title: "Region dealers",
            items: [
                {
                     xtype: "panel",
                     flex: 1,
                     items: [
                         {
                              id: "tab-region-dealers",
                              xtype: "salepoint"
                         }
                     ]
                  }, 
                  {
                      xtype: "tabpanel",
                      flex: 2,
                      items: [
                          {
                               id: "tab-operator-list",
                               title: "Operator list",
                               xtype: "operator"
                           }
                       ]
                    }
               ]
         }
]});
```

So I want to add `itemId` property will it break my project if I use the same `id` and `itemId` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't break. They are not mutually exclusive. You just have to follow these 2 rules:

1. *itemId* should be unique within it's container;
2. *id* should be unique across all existing components.

In the long run, I would suggest getting rid of *id*s.

Comment: Yes, we can keep id and itemId similar, no issues.But as mentioned in above comment keep id unique in app.